# iOS UIBarButtonItem link to ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a question about the `UIBarButtonItem` to link to another ViewController in the Storyboard. In this top bar I have 2 icons on the Right do this with a array:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_meetupButton, _searchButton, nil]];
```

Both buttons work in the console, but when I want to navigate with the `meetupButton` to another ViewController, it doesn't work.

Storyboard name is Main
ViewController is correctly linked to `MeetupStartViewController`.

When he runs the following code he crashes. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)toggleMeetup:(UIButton *)button {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MeetupStartViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Error log:

> 2015-09-08 15:46:46.554 APPNAME[2267:530587] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'MeetupStartViewController''
>
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x184e9022c 0x196b640e4 0x189eced3c 0x1000f90f0 0x1899411ec 0x1899411ec 0x18992a2c8 0x189940b88 0x189940814 0x189939d50 0x18990cf74 0x189bae124 0x18990b488 0x184e47f8c 0x184e47230 0x184e452e0 0x184d70f74 0x18e7cb6fc 0x189972d94 0x1000a2764 0x19720ea08)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

The `MeetupStartViewController` is a Swift class the other code is Objective-C.

Comment: can you paste the crashlog ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot, see my post.

Comment: did you set the explicit ID for MeetupStartViewController in Storyboards? it seems that it cant be found ?

Comment: Yes that was the solution, I've add a name to the Storyboard ID view and replace the class name with this name. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have not set the required ID for MeetupStartViewController.

To do so, go in to storyboards, select MeetupStartViewController. 
Check the box for: use Storyboard ID and write "MeetupStartViewController" in the StoryboardID box. Here is a visual example:

[image]